# Sufficient condition for the independence of random variable and the event

Tags: probability, random-variables, fourier-series, independence

I would like to prove the following proposition:
Let $X$ be a random variable on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. If 
$$
\mathbb{E}(1_{B}\times e^{iuX})=\mathbb{P}(B)\times \mathbb{E}(e^{iuX})
$$
for any $u\in \mathbb{R}$, then random variable $X(\omega)$  and event $B$ are independent.

The idea of the proof is the following:

**Step 1:** let $f(x)$ be, say, continuously differentiable $2\pi$-periodic function. Then it is well-known that its Fourier series $\sum_{|n|\le N}c_ne^{inx} \to f(x)$ for any $x$ as $n\to \infty$. Using linearity of mathematical expectation, it is easy to show that following is valid
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(1_{B}\times \sum_{|n|\le N}c_ne^{inX(\omega)}\right)=\mathbb{P}(B)\times \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{|n|\le N}c_ne^{inX(\omega)}\right)
$$
Then tending $n\to \infty$ in equality above, we see that 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(1_{B}\times f(X)\right)=\mathbb{P}(B)\times \mathbb{E}(f(X))
$$
where $f$ is a continuously differentiable $2\pi$-periodic function.

**Step 2:** By considering function $F(x)=f(\frac{x}{K})$, we can extend it to continuously differentiable $2\pi K$-periodic function for arbitrary $K$.

**Step 3:** Then we can further extend it to arbitrary continuously differentiable function.

**Step 4:** Next, we can approximate the indicator of function $1_A(x)$ by a sequence of continuously differentiable functions, which means that 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(1_{B}\times 1_A(X)\right)=\mathbb{P}(B)\times \mathbb{P}(X\in A)
$$
And it proves that indeed random variable $X(\omega)$ and set $B$ are independent.

I know that my proof is not strictly speaking complete, but I was just wondering if there's any shorter prooof? Or may be this result follows from some other, more well-known , sufficient condition for independence?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a theorem which says that if $X, Y$ are random variables then ($\perp$ denotes independence)
   $$ X \perp Y\iff \mathbb{E}e^{iuX+ivY}=\mathbb{E}e^{iuX}\mathbb{E}e^{ivY} \forall_{u,v\in\mathbb{R}}.$$
   It follows from the fact that Fourier transform uniquely determines a probability measure.
2. For an event $B$, if $1_B$ is the indicator function of $B$,
   $$\mathbb{E}e^{iv1_B} = \mathbb{P}(B)e^{iv} + \mathbb{P}(B^c).$$
3. Now, from our assumption,
   $$\mathbb{E}e^{iuX+iv1_B} = e^{iv}\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{E}e^{iuX} + \mathbb{P}(B^c)\mathbb{E}e^{iuX} = \mathbb{E}e^{iv1_B}\mathbb{E}e^{iuX}.$$
   Therefore we are allowed to use 1.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just thinking about rougly the same: $e^{iu1_B(X(\omega))}$ (which takes two values) can be reduced to $1_B(X(\omega))$ via some shift and scaling.More specifically, $e^{iu1_B(X(\omega))}=1_B(X(\omega)\times (e^{iu}-1)+1$.

Comment: Excuse me for being a little slow...  How / where did you use the assumption that $\mathbb{E}(1_{B}\times e^{iuX})=\mathbb{P}(B)\times \mathbb{E}(e^{iuX})$?  I think you mean to use it in step 3, but the details escape me.  Do you mind writing it out in more details?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing; in step 3 you split the integral into one over $B$ and one over $B^c$. Then on $B$, $e^{iv1_B}$ reduces to $e^{iv}$ and on $B^c$ it reduces to $1$. Now you move the constants in front of the integrals and use the assumption for $B$ and $B^c$ respectively.

Comment: +1 Ah, I see, thanks!  You're splitting $E[Z] = E[(1_B + 1_{B^c}) Z]$ and in particular $\mathbb{E}(1_{B^c}\times e^{iuX})=\mathbb{P}(B^c)\times \mathbb{E}(e^{iuX})$ also follows from this split plus the main assumption.